# Custom Filter in Views using Drupal 7

Tags: views, 7

i have a content type having two major fields.

A  and B

Now i want to get all resutls of those nodes .

if A having value of 1 or B having value of 2.

if anyof node matched with one field i need to show result.

How to do this in views ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this using below step:

- Go to Administration -> Structure -> Views
- Edit your existing view or create new new.
- Add Filter 'A' and B in your view
- Click on "Rearrange" filter icon in Filter section
- Click on "Create new filter group" and move filter "A" and "B" in new filter group.
- Select Operator as "Or" in new filter group and save the form.

[image: Views filter group]

Comment: can we do this on CONTEXTUAL FILTERS itsled

Comment: No, there is no simple method for contextual filter. You need to alter views query for contextual filter.